# Adjust Windows DNS timeout similar to the Linux resolv.conf?

Tags: linux, windows, domain-name-system

I'm curious if there's a mechanism to adjust the Windows client resolver timeout in the same manner that the "timeout" option in the Linux `/etc/resolv.conf` file works.

For example, my Linux `resolv.conf` file often looks like:

```
search abc123.net
option timeout:1
nameserver 172.16.2.14
nameserver 172.16.2.18
nameserver 172.16.4.10
```

My timeout is 1 second between name server attempts.

How does this work on the Windows side?

If there is a mechanism to do this, is it commonly applied?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can make the change by adding a registry key. Microsoft has instructions here: http://technet.microsoft.com/library/Cc977482

In case that link stops working, here's the summary:

Use regedit to add `DNSQueryTimeouts` as a multi-string value to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters`. Then add five values indicating the number of seconds that each time limit is applied to the corresponding attempt in the name resolution process. Add a sixth value of zero.

1. Query the preferred DNS server on a preferred connection.
2. Query the preferred DNS server on all connections.
3. Query all DNS servers on all connections (1st attempt).
4. Query all DNS servers on all connections (2nd attempt).
5. Query all DNS servers on all connections (3rd attempt).
6. Must be zero (to indicate the end of the list)

The default values are

```
1
2
2
4
8
0
```

Comment: Is it common to modify this?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't say. I know that it exists, but I've never had a need to adjust it. FWIW, I've never encountered anyone who has told me that they've changed it.